# Heavily packed javascript, multiple questions from 219-byte (canvas, bitwise,...)

Tags: javascript, canvas, bit-manipulation

I came across a [website](http://quaxio.com/tron/) today. It was a challenge of some developers about making the smallest game possible with certain requirements, and they released the final code of unbelievable size of 219 bytes and runnable on Chrome 17 (one of the requirements). I tried to explore the code (with the explanation provided from the site) and do researches on codes I didn't comprehend. However, the code was packed too heavily to my knowledge, so I am seeking for some helps.

Here is the code, after beautified:

```
<body id=b onkeyup=e=event onload=
    z=c.getContext('2d');
    z.fillRect(s=0,0,n=150,x=11325);
    setInterval("
        0<x%n
        &x<n*n
        &(z[x+=[1,-n,-1,n][e.which&3]]^=1)?
        z.clearRect(x%n,x/n,1,1,s++)
        :b.innerHTML='GameOver:'+s
    ",9)>
<canvas id=c>
```

The game is named "Tron", and just like classic snake game (without apple).

Anyway, here are my questions:

**1) How can they select element with id 'c' without using `getElementById()` rather than a simple `c`**

Look at the bottom of the code, there is a canvas with `<canvas id=c>`. I understand that advanced browsers will automatically fix the quotes `""` for the `id="c"`. However, when a function is called in `onload` event, it assigns `z = c.getContent('2d');` and directly refers to the canvas without even applying anything such as `document.getElementById()`. Also the same when they referred to `<body id=b>`. How is that possible? Under which circumstances am I able to do similarly?

**2) Will replacing parameters of a functions by quick assigning variables affect the function at all? If it does, how will it be calculated?**

Particularly, take a look of the third line:

```
z.fillRect(s = 0, 0, n = 150, x = 11325);
```

I understand to the most basic level, `fillRect()` requires 4 parameters `fillRect(x-cor, y-cor, width, height)`. However, the code above produces a rectangle 150x150. First of all, I read the description and they claimed that by default, the code would produce a rectangle 300x150, so I assumed that the assigning short functions would actually assign nothing to the parameters of the parent function. I did a test, and replaced `n = 150` by `n = 200`. Weirdly enough, it produces a rectangle 200x150, so once again I agree that `n = 150` did assign `150` to that slot. Hence, the code above can be written as:

```
z.fillRect(0, 0, 150, 11325);
```

However, another problem comes. Why isn't its height 11325px but 150px instead? I thought it was reset to default because 11325 excessed the handling of browsers, so I changed it to 500 instead; and it produced the same problem.

So generally, when you do short assigning inside a function (for instance: `someCustomFunction.call(s = 1)`), what really happens there? If nothing happens, why did the rectangle in the example above changed its size when replacing `n = 200` but not when `x = 200`?

*Additional question: this question is not the question I am really into, because it is too personal, but I would love to know. The source states that "x is going to be the tron's position, and is set to 11325 (11325 = 75 x 75 + 75 = center of the grid)", how does this kind of one-number-represents-position work?*

**3) What in the world does it mean?**

This is the most headache part to me, because the author packed it too smartly.

```
&(z[x+=[1,-n,-1,n][e.which&3]]^=1)?
```

I broke it up, and figured that it was actually z[]^=1 in order to check the condition for the later `? :` operators. But first:

**What does `^=1` do?**

Some people [commented](http://www.reddit.com/r/javascript/comments/raee3/tron_in_226_bytes_of_js/) on the project and said it could be replaced by `--`. I think of it as a bitwise AND operator, but what does it have to do with `--`?

And next:

**How did they use `[e.which&3]` together with the preset array to filter keystroke "i", "j", "k", "l" too effectively?**

I notice the array has the length of 4, which is the length of the keys needs filtering. Also, pressing another key rather than "i", "j", "k", "l" also works. It leads me to believe that the `&3` does something in filtering the 4 keys, but I don't know how.

Those are all I have to ask. The short but complicated code really excites me, and I really appreciate any help in understanding the code further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sidenote: I didn't actually look at the website, so if I'm covering anything they already have, I'm sorry. I realised there was a link to it halfway through my post.

Here is the code, unminified, with some adjustments.

HTML:

```
<body id=b>
    <canvas id=c></canvas>
</body>
```

Javascript:

```
document.body.onkeyup = handleOnKeyUp;
document.body.onload = handleOnLoad;

function handleOnKeyUp(event) {
    e = event;
}
function handleOnLoad(event) {
    score = 0, n = 150, x = 11325;
    context = c.getContext('2d');
    context.fillRect(0, 0, n, n);
    end = setInterval(function () {
        if (typeof e === "undefined") return; // This isn't part of the original code - removes errors before you press a button
        // Map key that was pressed to a "direction"
        // l(76) i (73) j(74) k(75).
        // If you AND those values with 3, you'd get 
        // l(0), i(1), j(2), k(3)
        var oneDimDirs = [1, -n, -1, n];
        var dirChoice = oneDimDirs[e.which & 3];

        // Now add the chosen "direction" to our position
        x += dirChoice;
        if (x % n <= 0 || n * n <= x || // out of bounds
            !(context[x] ^= 1) // already passed through here
           ) {
            b.innerHTML = "GameOver:" + score;
            clearInterval(end);
        }
        else {
            score++;
            context.clearRect(x % n,x / n, 1 , 1)
        }
    }, 9);
}
```

Generally, the code makes heavy use of a couple of hacks:

1. It makes heavy use of global variables and the fact that assigning to an undefined variable creates a global.
2. It also makes use of irrelevant function parameters to set or modify variables(this shortens the code length)
3. The code uses a one-dimensional representation of a two-dimensional space. Instead of moving you in two directions, x and y, it "flattens" the representation of the two-dimensional space(the gameboard) into a one-dimensional array. `x` represents your position on the overall game board. If you add 1 to x, you will move along the current "line"(until you get to its end). Adding n moves you a whole line forward, so it's similar to moving once down.

Your questions, one by one:

**1) How can they select element with id 'c' without using getElementById() rather than a simple c**

Kooilnc's answer already covers this. This is called "named access":

http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/#named-access-on-the-window-object

**2) Will replacing parameters of a functions by quick assigning variables affect the function at all? If it does, how will it be calculated?**

You misunderstood what is happening here. First, functions accept *values* as their parameters, and expressions produce *values* when they are evaluated. An assignment expression, `n = 150`, produces the value `150` when evaluated. As a side effect, it also assigns that value to the variable n. So calling a function `func(n = 150)` is almost equivalent to `func(150)`, with the exception of that side effect. That side effect is used in the code to save space, instead of having to assign the variables on separate lines.

Now, for the canvas WTF - As far as I can tell, a canvas element's default width and height happen to be 300px and 150px. You cannot draw past those limits, so trying to execute `z.fillRect(0, 0, 150, 11325);` will not draw past the 150 height limit. The code authors use the fact that 11325 is bigger than 150 and is thus safe to pass as a parameter(the rectangle will still be drawn as 150x150). 11325 happens to be the one-dimensional coordinate of the starting position.

**3) What in the world does it mean?**

I hope I mostly answered it within the code. The inner part is unpacked and commented, which only leaves this part unexplained:

`context[x] ^= 1.`

(Note, `^ === XOR`)
The idea is that the authors are using the context as an array to store which positions they've already visited. There are three reasons for doing it this way:

One, they want to assign some value to mark that they've passed through here. context[x] is usually `undefined`, `undefined ^ 1 === 1`, so they're assigning ones to the positions they pass through.

Next, they want to be able to check if they've passed through there. Coincidentally, `1 ^ 1 === 0`, which makes it easy to check. Note what I mentioned about assignment expressions - the value of this assignment expression will be either `1`, if the position has not been visited before, or `0`, if it has. This allows the authors to use it as a check.

Since the check they use is something like `expr & expr & expr`, expressions which yield true/false or 1/0 values will work the same way as if it was `expr && expr && expr`(`true` and `false` are converted to the numbers `1` and `0` when used in `&`)

**How did they use [e.which&3] together with the preset array to filter keystroke "i", "j", "k", "l" too effectively?**

I hope I answered this sufficiently with comments in the code. Basically, using the onkeyup handler, they store the event which has the key that was pressed. On the next interval tick, they check e.which to determine which direction to go in.

Comment: +1. Nice explanation. I didn't see this until I'd posted my answer (even though you answered first), but you covered everything nicely, including providing the details I missed. I planned to just post the (relatively) obvious parts first and then go back and tackle the really confusing parts, but you've already got it all covered.

Comment: First off, thank for the wonderful answers. #2: I am not sure about the limit. I try `z.fillRect(s = 0, 0, n = 150, x = 200);` and it doesn't work, even though 200 is not that bad. #3: Generally, any 0 & 0 & 0 and 1 & 1 & 1 will produce a true clause? It's a very good experience to know. Everything else is very well explained. Thank you very much. By the way, do you have any good source to learn about bitwise and it in practice? Besides Google.

Comment: 0 & 0 & 0 === 0, 1 & 1 & 1 === 1, also 1 & 1 ..... & 0 === 0...and so on. x = 200 will start you barely on the second "line" of the two-dim zone, if you press left or up you'd quickly get a game over.

Answer (score 1):

About

**1) How can they select element with id 'c' without using `getElementById()` rather than a simple `c`**

In most browsers you can access an element using its `ID` as a variable in the global namespace (i.e. `window`). In other words, to retrieve `<div id="c">` you can also use `c`, or `window.c`.

[**See also**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3434278/ie-chrome-are-dom-tree-elements-global-variables-here)

The other questions I leave to smarter people ;)

Comment: This is the most effective answer for my #1 question. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

> 1) How can they select element with id 'c' without using getElementById() rather than a simple c

I believe it was an old version of IE that originally allowed access of DOM elements in JS directly by their id, but a number of other browsers followed for compatibility with websites that rely on this. In general it's not a great thing because you can get weird bugs if you create variables with the same names as the element ids (not that that matters for this example).

> 2) Will replacing parameters of a functions by quick assigning variables affect the function at all? If it does, how will it be calculated?

You said within your point (2) that `z.fillRect(s = 0, 0, n = 150, x = 11325);` can be written instead as `z.fillRect(0, 0, 150, 11325);`, but that is true *only* in as far as having the function call to `fillRect()` work the same way. This change would break the overall program because the assignment statements are needed to create and set the `n` and `x` global variables.

In a general sense in JS the assignment operator `=` not only assigns the value from the right-hand operand to the variable on the left, but the whole expression gives the value of the right-hand operand. So `someFunc(x = 10)` sets the variable `x` to `10` and passes the value `10` to `someFunc()`.

In the case of that `fillRect()`, the `n` and `x` variables have not previously been declared, so assigning a value to them creates them as globals.

> 3) What in the world does it mean? `&(z[x+=[1,-n,-1,n][e.which&3]]^=1)?`

Well, it's (obviously) kind of complicated. To answer the specific questions you mentioned about parts of it:

> How did they use `[e.which&3]` together with the preset array to filter keystroke "i", "j", "k", "l" too effectively?

The keys "i", "j", "k", and "l" are a good choice for up/left/down/right controls in a game because their physical layout on a standard keyboard corresponds to up/left/down/right but also because those letters belong next to each other in the alphabet so they have contiguous keycodes too: `73, 74, 75, 76`. So when you take those keycodes and do a bitwise AND with `&3` you get the values `1, 2, 3, 0` which then act as appropriate indices into the `[1,-n,-1,n]` array.

> What does ^=1 do? ... I think of it as a bitwise AND operator ...

It's *not* a bitwise AND operator. `^` is a bitwise XOR, and `^=` is the bitwise XOR assignment operator. That is, `x ^= 1` is equivalent to `x = x ^ 1`.